# Write EPIPE error when using ffmpeg with copy option with ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, ytdl

Using the following code i get a write EPIPE error. This is caused by the copy option as when i remove that option it works just takes forever. Any idea what would be the fix to this?

```
const audio = ytdl(videoURL, { quality: 'highestaudio', filter: 'audioonly', highWaterMark: 1 << 25 })
            .on('progress', (_, downloaded, total) => {
                tracker.audio = { downloaded, total };
            });
const video = ytdl(videoURL, { quality: 'highestvideo' })
  .on('progress', (_, downloaded, total) => {
      tracker.video = { downloaded, total };
   });

const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
            '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
            '-progress', 'pipe:3',
            '-i', 'pipe:4',
            '-i', 'pipe:5',
            '-map', '0:a',
            '-map', '1:v',
            '-c:v', 'copy',
            'out.webm',
        ], {
            windowsHide: true,
            stdio: [
                'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
                'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
            ],
        });
        ffmpegProcess.on('close', () => {
            console.log('done');
        });

  
        ffmpegProcess.stdio[3].on('data', chunk => {
            if (!progressbarHandle) progressbarHandle = setInterval(showProgress, progressbarInterval);
            const lines = chunk.toString().trim().split('\n');
            const args = {};
            for (const l of lines) {
                const [key, value] = l.split('=');
                args[key.trim()] = value.trim();
            }
            tracker.merged = args;
        });
        audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
        video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue it seems that ffmpeg doesnt like the output file to be webm so i just changed it to an mp4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).